# Using jQuery's $.post in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, forms, firefox

The form I am testing out is:

```
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>
<div id="response"></div>
```

The jQuery I use to process the form is:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
  $.post("processform.php", $("#form").serialize(), function(response) {
    $("#response").html(response);
  });
  return false;
});
```

In Chrome, Firefox, and IE, everything works. I am able to shoot my form to the PHP and have it return what I want. However in Firefox, hitting submit only seems to refresh the page, which it shouldn't do at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, actually you only return false for the click event not for the actual form. To get your desired behavior try the following

```
$("#form").on('submit', function(e) {
  // this will help to prevent the default action - submit
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post("processform.php", $("#form").serialize(), function(response) {
    $("#response").html(response);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To whomever deleted their answer which worked for me.

Changing

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
  ...
  return false;
});
```

to

```
$("#form").submit(function() {
  ...
  return false;
});
```

works to cancel the submit button.

Comment: I wasn't able to duplicate the problem, so I wasn't sure if my solution would work. Glad it helped!

Answer (score -1):

replace `.click(...)` by `.submit(...)`.

and wrap your code inside

```
$(function(){

   ... YOUR CODE HERE

});
```

Comment: Explain the minus 1 ?